# facebook error 'Error validating verification code'

Tags: php, facebook, urlencode

very strange error. i use gide http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/. so i create request to fb and pass redirect_uri. i use test site on localhost. so if i pass

> redirect_uri=http://localhost/test_blog/index.php

it works fine, but if i pass

> redirect_uri=http://localhost/test_blog/index.php?r=site/oauth2

it don't want work. i try to use

> redirect_uri= .
>   urlencode('http://localhost/test_blog/index.php?r=site/oauth2)

but not work. 
i try to explaine. i success get code, but when i access https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token i get error 'Error validating verification code'. i checked evering, error is in **?r=site/oauth2** but i need passing some params
can somebody help me?
i read post http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=70855 but nothing work for me

Comment: i see that we can use url rewriting like http://localhost/tes...php/site/oauth2 but it's simply interesting how to solve the problem

Answer (score 128, accepted):

There are presently (as of March 2011) undocumented requirements regarding what makes a valid redirect_uri.

First, **both redirect_uri paramaters to authorize and access_token must match**.

Apparently Facebook (or rather OAuth2) is using the redirect_uri as a internal key to encode the code returned for the access_token request. It's kinda clever since it verifies back to your site. It explains why the access_token request which wouldn't otherwise need a redirect_uri parameter requires one.

Second, **you cannot use many special characters in the redirect_uri**.

A lot of discussion rages whether parameters can be passed at all. They can, you're limited which characters are valid but no one has published a list that I know. Traditional methods like url/html encoding will fail because percent(%) is not valid. Slash (/) is not valid either so a nested redirection url will always fail. The ONLY way to overcome the special char limitation is to encode the value of the parameter to base64. If you're using ASP.NET, look up Convert.ToBase64.

Lastly, and this is more of a side-note. There are a lot of programmers passing along misinformation that a simple solution is to pass type=client_cred. This may limit your access to some of the permissions you requested in your authorization. It is inadvisable.

Comment: Had no idea redirect_uri had to match on both (although it makes sense). This question keeps on giving, even months later :)

Comment: Awesome, Michael! I had the same problem where I didn't have the same redirect_uri params for both auth and access_token, calls. --FFS--

Comment: Most Base64 encodings contains Slash (/). Make sure you use an url safe encoder

Comment: This response saved me a bunch of time.  Thanks! Given that FB knows what the error is, I wonder why they don't make the message more descriptive.

Comment: Trailing slashes, or lack thereof. Watch out for them.

Comment: I wish I had found this answer an hour ago. I've been trying to embed a URL in the redirect_uri and could not figure out what was going on. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 55):

Had the same problem all day when testing with `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000` (encoded to `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000`)...

Solution was simply to make sure to put the trailing slash `/` on the end of the uri. So `redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/` (encoded to `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F`).

Again, make sure the `redirect_uri` is identical for both requests.

Comment: 2 hours... 2 hours of wasted time for this... Thank you

Comment: 1 hour wasted - Thank you!

Comment: 2 days - Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hours wasted. Adding Slash didnt change anything for me.

Answer (score 19):

I have had this problem. I knew for a fact that my URLs were the same because I used a class with the same $var, but I kept getting the 400 response and that error in the JSON response.

The only thing I did was change my redirect_uri from:

```
http://myredirecturi.com
```

to

```
http://myredirecturi.com/
```

Yeh, just added the trailing slash and it worked.

Comment: Had the same issue but on Java. Unbelievable that a trailing slash solved it :( OOOF. Thanks.

Comment: You are super hero. ‍♂️

Answer (score 8):

You don't really need to encode, just put the '/' at the end of your redirect_url and everything should be fine!

Answer (score 6):

Part of the information given by Aaron Wheeler is incorrect.

It is true that the 'redirect_uri' parameter must be identical in both requests, however **it is perfectly possible to URL encode a regular URL** and use that as the value for the 'redirect_url' parameter, so long as you're careful to further URL encode any inline URLs.

For instance, you wish facebook to redirect to the following URL:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Users/oAuthComplete?my_param_1=/Party/pants
```

Attempting to redirect the user to

```
'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&redirect_uri='
. urlencode('http://www.mysite.com/Users/oAuthComplete?my_param_1=/Party/pants');
```

Will fail as `/Party/Pants` creates an invalid URL

However, redirecting to

```
'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=12345&redirect_uri='
.urlencode('http://www.mysite.com/Users/oAuthComplete?my_param_1='
.urlencode('/Party/pants'));
```

Will work as expected.

If you are using the returned the redrect_uri value in the second, authenticate application request, be sure to url encode again - **the value is automatically URL decoded when populating the $_GET superglobal**. - This is what tripped me up.

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=12345&&client_secret=SECRET&code=1234567'
.urlencode('http://www.mysite.com/Users/oAuthComplete?my_param_1='
.urlencode($_GET['my_param_1']));
```

P.s. In your actual code, I'd recommend using sprintf() rather than chaining string together like in my example, for better readability.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can see, the problem here is that the redirect_uri must end with '/' and not contain '?' or other special characters. I think that is why you are getting 'Error validating verification code'. This error only appears if you are using file_get_contents(), and not when using the facebook php library.
This is the solution for php, don't know if this error appears in other SDK's.

Comment: removing ? from the url sovled the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it will help, but i would suggest to encode only values in the url. Not the whole thing. eg:

```
redirect_uri='http://localhost/test_blog/index.php?r='.urlencode('site/oauth2');
```

Comment: this one worked for me - it must be the '/' in the parameter which caused the problem - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the pb and finally fix it adding the type=client_cred parameter in the url.

Comment: I would not recommend this. The type=client_cred param is for a different use case.

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this for a while. Since I didn't want a redirect, but the redirect parameter is required, my solution was to **simply set it to nothing** -

```
...&redirect_uri=&client_secret=...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

Admittedly, I am a super n00b so excuse me if this solution doesnt make any sense in actual practice.

I simply set a short fuse cookie (1-2 min) with a test variable in the page with my FB Connect button. When FB came back with information to my data parsing/handling script I checked for this cookie where I was redirecting it and if found, directed the user to the proper URL using header:location.

Of course some browsers/users etc disable cookies. This obviously wont work there (maybe use a session var and destroy it in the fb data handler?) I am sure there is a better way to do it but at the moment, this bandaid works.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using Yii which I'm using as well and had the same problem for half the day. As mentioned, the problem is the special characters in your URL `i.e. r=site/oath2`

You can fix it by enabling pretty URLS in your config so that your URL becomes `index.php/site/oath2`

It seems to work without the trailing slash though.

Comment: Where would I go to enable pretty URLs in the config?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();     
if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => '',
        'redirect_uri' => $this->domain,
    ));
    print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
}
```

I've been cracking my head a long time before I found this solution, seeming I am not the only one with this issue I hope this works for you to!