# batch app to user notifications in facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to batch send [App-to-User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications) notifications?
Currently I send them one by one using a `POST` request to the `/{recipient_userid}/notifications` edge using a php script, and it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

```php
$userIds = ['100000000000000','100000000000001', '100000000000002']; // Users who will receive the notification.
$notificationMessage = 'Test message!'; // Notification message. Character limit: 180, truncate after 120.
$linkHref = 'posts/123'; // Path after Facebook Web Games URL that facebook's iframe will display on notification click.
$analyticsRef = 'new-posts'; // Group notifications for App Analytics.

var_dump(sendBatchRequests($userIds, $notificationMessage, $linkHref, $analyticsRef));

function sendBatchRequests($ids, $message, $href = '', $ref = null) {
    $APP_ACCESS_TOKEN = '123456789012345|AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz'; // How to create one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831913/1494454
    $FACEBOOK_BATCH_ELEMENT_LIMIT = 50; // Maximum amount of request grouped into a batch. Facebook's limit is 50: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#limits

    $results = [];
    $idChunks = array_chunk($ids, $FACEBOOK_BATCH_ELEMENT_LIMIT);
    foreach ($idChunks as $idChunk) {
        $batch = [];
        foreach ($idChunk as $id) {
            $batch[] = [
               'method' => 'POST',
               'relative_url' => "{$id}/notifications?template={$message}" . ($ref ? "&ref={$ref}" : ''),
            ];
        }
        $results[] = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/', false, stream_context_create([
            'http' => [
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                'content' => json_encode([
                    'access_token' => $APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    'batch' => $batch,
                ]),
            ],
        ]));
    }
    return $results;
}
```

### Explanation

There is an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/aloktherocker/facebook-batch-notification/blob/master/batch_notify.php) on how to do this, but it is really old, so I created a modern, up-to-date one inspired by it. Both the [notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications) and the [guide to do batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) are well documented, so you just need to implement it which can be done in vanilla PHP.

The `sendBatchRequests` function will send a notification with the `$message` text for every user given in `$userIds`. It will group every `$FACEBOOK_BATCH_ELEMENT_LIMIT` amount of requests into batches and fires one HTTP request per batch. The API response is stored in `$results`.   Clicking the notification will redirect the user to your app's Facebook Web Games URL inside the Facebook Games iframe. You can specify the path **after** that URL with `$linkHref`. `$ref` is for analytic purposes. See more in the documentation linked above.

This is just an example. You still have to make sure that there will be a request for every user and the script doesn't time out and check whether the request was successful.