# OAuth Exception issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

The following URL causes an OAuth exception.  I have no idea why this is as locally this is working OK.  It is only when it is on the domain does it fail.  The app is configured correctly each time in the Facebook App.  Note this is using the `FacebookScopedClient` code [Here](http://savvydev.com/authenticating-facebook-users-with-mvc-4-oauth-and-obtaining-scope-permissions/).  Any direction would be appreciated

**URL**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=52*********37&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2ffreersvp.mytakeawaysite.com%3a80%2fAccount%2fExternalLoginCallback%3fReturnUrl%3d%252FDashboard%26__provider__%3dFacebook%2bPro%26__sid__%3d3c92eb7e84304afc931ef0ea7b62f56a&client_secret=2123***********4256&code=AQAQIJsj-ondldllVYKdpxJaZouqrlg9sjTcfUxyWhAw8MXbD2DvsOSujg2m7E3s3cvNusCI0ZZoJAuGgu_FLkPyjYMQAkTWDVyHTcAoJD-tezyXgn0vhoFzX3FmuRBHYpyJEM-dk0KgF5ugsTHo9yGjBjrcfMDUGu9IxkKQ36k3gMrwocM1_l5t342Q2kIOHdt8pPcyrs--NzgNyZv48vSq7jkZwuQ95xRjUHG5J-ptcgq0l2BlqjzHDDuvIFH23lpMWHzzqdejdj5ejukz7t_Fnhx-mrpVdcRYhP3JeZ2UOTjAyKQmUB3rInooECcjq4c
```

**Exception**

```
{
       "error": {
          "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "code": 100
       }
    }
```

Comment: is your `ExternalLoginCallback` correct?

Comment: Hi christanddev what do you mean is it correct?  the callback goes to an action called ExternalLoginCallback

Comment: You seem to have a nested url featuring a `/` in your redirect_uri ( `...?ReturnUrl=/Dashboard&__provider__=Facebook` ) If so, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5389447/1236044 might solve your problem (the base64 encoding seems promising)

Answer (score 0):

try this uri

```
m_OAuthURL = new Uri(
    string.Format(
          "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&&scope={2}&response_type=token", 
          AppID, RedirectUri, Scope));
```

when you use this redirect uri:

```
string k_RedirectUri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
```

hope it will help for me it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL in the Facebook app config and make sure you have correctly configured.

```
  http://www. or http://
```

also make sure to check the trailing slash.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the redirect_uri in both /dialog/oauth and /oauth/access_token is the same.